# My string does not match my regex even though it is correct on regex101

Tags: java, android, regex

I am having this weird problem in Android Studio wherein my program cannot parse the String I am matching through regex.

```
private Pattern myPattern = Pattern.compile("([Request ID:]+)(\\d+)([, BY:]+)(\\d+)([ ])([A-Z\\d ]+)([ ])([amount:]+)(\\d+(\\.\\d{1,2}))");

     msg = "Request ID:22, BY:123414045601 DEALER01 amount:100.00 | Request ID:41, BY:123414012341 DEALER01 amount:100.00 | Request ID:2, BY:123414032110 DEALER MAKER5 amount:500.00";

    String[] items = msg.split("\\|");
    for(int i = 0; i <items.length; i++){

        Matcher match = pendingPattern.matcher(items[i]);
        if (!match.matches()) {

        } else {

            list1.add(match.group(2));
            list2.add(match.group(4));
            list3.add(match.group(9));
        }
    }
```

My regex matches "Request ID:2, BY:123414032110 DEALER MAKER5 amount:500.00" but doesnt match the other entries. I have already checked this on regex101.com and all of my entries matches there.

Your insight about this is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is because of spaces before and after `|` in your input.

You can use `String.trim()` to get rid of it like:

```
Matcher match = pendingPattern.matcher(items[i].trim());
```

Or else don't let spaces appear in split array by using this regex in split:

```
String[] items = msg.split("\\s*\\|\\s*");
```

Comment: Thank you very much! This solved my problem. I didn't thought that the white spaces have such an impact.